# Reformat Mobile Number to the required Mobile Connect format?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Mobile Studio has exact mobile number format requirements:

- Example: 61431123456
- No proceeding + symbol
- Country code, i.e. for Australia: 61
- Mobile number with no spaces
- No proceeding 0 on the mobile number (i.e. not 610431123456)

Question: how in Marketing Cloud can we accept 'dirty data' (i.e. mobile numbers not in the above format) from an external source, and then reformat the data to the required format?

We normally solve this issue in Sales Cloud, but currently working on a project with Marketing Cloud only!

Comment: I would do this by using query activity in Automation Studio. Exactly how to do this depends on how “dirty” your data is. Can you provide some examples?

Comment: Like @LukasLunow says, it depends on how random the data you have. I also tend to load into a staging table and manipulate using query activities. An example of common Aussie phone number formats rendered for SFMC is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjg3linjn48awhi/5%20-%20Get%20MobileContacts.txt?dl=0 and you'll need to repurpose for your own use case. It's all about painful string manipulation, but the above does the stripping of usual junk characters etc.